# Delphi out of memory error when i load file to memory stream

Tags: delphi, memory

I want to convert a 2GB file to an array of byte with Delphi. I use this function, then load file into memory Stream to get bytes. But I get error "Out of memory". How I can solve this problem?

```
type
TByteArray  =  Array of Byte;

function StreamToByteArray(Stream: TStream): TByteArray;
begin

// Check stream
if Assigned(Stream) then
begin
// Reset stream position
Stream.Position:=0;
// Allocate size
SetLength(result, Stream.Size);
// Read contents of stream
Stream.Read(result[0], Stream.Size);
end
else
// Clear result
SetLength(result, 0);
end;
//////then in button control i use:
var
strmMem: TMemoryStream;
bytes: TByteArray;
begin
strmMem:=TMemoryStream.Create;
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
strmMem.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
bytes:=StreamToByteArray(strmMem);
strmMem.Free;
```

Comment: Why hold such a large file in memory? (And twice).

Answer (score 18):

A 32 bit process has a total of 4GB of address space. Unless it has the large address aware flag available, only 2GB of that address space is available to it.

You are attempting to load a 2GB file into memory, in a contiguous block of address space. There is no chance of you being able to succeed. Even with a large address aware 4GB address space there's little hope for you finding a contiguous 2GB block of address space.

Furthermore, you are also attempting to read the file into memory twice, so you actually need two 2GB contiguous blocks. One for the stream, and one for the array. This is a result of you using the *memory stream anti-pattern* as described below.

Some options:

- Switch to a 64 bit process, or
- load the entire file, but in discontinuous blocks, or
- process the file piece by piece, in smaller chunks.

---

Regarding the use of a memory stream, this is a recurring anti-pattern. I'd say that >90% of the uses of memory streams that we see here in the Delphi Stack Overflow tag are needless and wasteful.

The mistake is to load into memory just to be able to copy to some other memory. You are trying to read the file into an array. So read it directly into an array. The memory stream is pointless. Use a file stream. Read from the file stream into the array. That way you only load a single copy of the file into memory.

Of course, you'll sill struggle to put a 2GB file into memory even with that change, but you should still aim to hold only one copy of the data in memory.